# Should I start posting my questions on MO?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, math-stackexchange, scope

I have been a member of MO and of math.SE for a long time now. My participation in MO has been mainly lurking because I am not a researcher but a student who aims to become one. So, logically, I have been much more active on math.SE.

However, on the last months my questions have started getting very little attention: little upvotes, little answers. Of course, it might be because their quality has fallen. It might also be a [generalized tendency](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11936/concern-about-lesser-attention-towards-relatively-advanced-questions).

So I have started wondering if I should start posting some of my questions on MO. Instead of just asking for migration, I thought it would be wiser to ask here beforehand. I apologize if this is inappropriate. Here are the latest examples:

[Special representation for morphisms of spectra from a smash product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730278/special-representations-for-morphisms-of-spectra-from-a-smash-product) (12 views, 0 upvotes)

[If a morphism of pushouts of complexes (with one arrow monic) is composed of quasi-isos, then the induced arrow is one also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712289/if-a-morphism-of-pushouts-of-complexes-with-one-arrow-monic-is-composed-of-qua) (31 views, 1 upvote, 1 partial answer)

[What does it mean to speak of a homotopy fibration sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684763/what-does-it-mean-to-speak-of-a-homotopy-fibration-sequence) (38 views, 0 upvotes)

What do you think?

Comment: The questions have now been migrated to MO:

[Morphisms of spectra][1]

[Homotopy fibration sequences][2]


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162209/special-representations-for-morphisms-of-spectra-from-a-smash-product
  [2]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162212/what-does-it-mean-to-speak-of-a-homotopy-fibration-sequence

Answer (score 16):

In my view, your questions are at a good level for MO.  A good indication of this is that (as you implicitly point out) you're getting lots of upvotes but almost no answers on MSE.

I like the detail you put into your questions, and I think that will go down well.  If you're asking questions as a result of going through textbooks and getting stuck, probably the most important points are (i) to keep up that level of detail, (ii) to make sure you've made a sustained effort to answer the question yourself before asking on MO, and (iii) to make it clear in your question that you've made that effort.

Comment: Thanks! I will wait a day or two to see if this really is what the community thinks (well, the part of the community that visits meta.MO) and if it seems to be the case then I'll ask for migration of the first and third questions (not the second one as I have already found an answer myself (with external help)). I will also take this opportunity to thank you for your wonderful set of notes of category theory. They were incredibly useful for the writing of my bachelor's thesis some two years ago, and they provided amazing insight not written elsewhere. So thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, Bruno, that's very kind.  They're actually about to be published as a book.

Comment: I'm really very happy to hear about that!